# I need to create a unique code from value variables of a java object

Tags: java, object, hashcode, unique-key

I've thought about:

```
codeUnique=Math.abs(film.hashCode()+((Integer)numero).hashCode()+
                    ((Integer)fornitura).hashCode();
```

But use the hashCode is not ok because it isn't unique, it changes in time. Variables are these:

```
    private int numero;
    private String film;
    private int fornitura;
```

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly does a hashcode change in time?  Are you mutating those values?  If you change the values, then the hash of those values *should* change.

Comment: You can't use fields you mutate for the `hashCode`, `equals` or `compareTo`.

Comment: BTW `((Integer)numero).hashCode()` is just `numero` but slower.

Comment: here http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/ say it could change

Comment: BTW Math.abs() can return a negative value.

Comment: @anto150192 Object.hashCode() can be different between different executions of an application. A single object cannot change it's hashCode once it is added to a hash collection (for keys and elements) without corrupting it.

Comment: @anto150192 Why it has to be unique?

Comment: Unique hashCodes will still get collisions in a Hash Collection unless you have a capacity of 4 billion (i.e. a 32-bit index) This is because the hashCode has to be reduced to a reasonable size e.g. number of bits, to save space.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, there will be collsions, but that are managed by the hash table (when having a correct equals method). Therefore my question why it has to be unique?

Comment: @AlexWien When you said "I consider this as unique." I was making the point that it is easy to show it's not, though I agree it hardly matters as you will get collisions when you reduce the hashCode to the number of buckets you have.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a unique code, this is a very strange and surprising requirement. Please explain, so that we can be of help.

Comment: because I have to add any article in a basket and every article need to be identified by a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough a hashcode don't has to be unique, the code below
should give in practise practically unique result, when numero or fornitura do not get negative,
which is most likely the case.
There is little chance that this code will not deliver a unique result for
real world data input.

If you don't want to rely on that asumptions, then you have to introduce
 your own unique id which you generate when the object is constructed.

For creation of hascodes. See also: Josh Bloch: Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 9

In many cases you don't need a unique id, a suitable hashcode would look as follows:

```
public int hashCode() {
  int result = 17;
  result = 31 * result + numero;
  result = 31 * result + fornitura;
  if (film != null) {
    result = 31 * result + film.hashCode();
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you need a practically unique code, unique for real world data,
without going the expensive way of creating and looking up unique codes in
 data (-base), you could try this:
It uses long instead of int.

(Remember whole life, does not need any garuantee, it's all a question of probability)

```
public long uniqueCode() {
      long result = 17;
      result = 31 * result + numero;
      result = 31 * result + Long.MAX_VALUE << 16 + fornitura;
      result = 31 * result + Long.MAX_VALUE << 32 + stringCode(film);
      return result;
  }

  public static long stringCode(String s) {
     if (s == null) return 0;
     long h = 0;
     int len = s.length();
     for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          h = 31*h + s.charAt(i);
     }
     return h;
  }
```

Comment: While this is cleaner code, I don't see how it answers the question.

Comment: I consider this as unique. The only weak point is String.hashcode, but still I asume this in praxis as unique. I looked at the src of String,hashcode(); I doubt anybody can show me an example where the above code will not deliver a uniqe code

Comment: Uniqueness is hard to guarentee and no guarentee you won't get collisions. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2015/09/an-introduction-to-optimising-hashing.html

Comment: For example, a tricky exercise is to a) load a dictionary of words, b) generate strings of words which have a hashCode of 0, c) generate haiku which have a hashCode of 0 (5 / 7 / 5 syllables)

Comment: If you have `fornitura = -numero * 31` and `film = null` they will all create the same hashCode.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No exitsing film name in the world will be such a tricky string.

Comment: If you have 64K values, it is highly likely that any two values will have the same 32-bit hash.

Comment: I dont see 64k values; fornitura and numero are int32.

Comment: You were talking about film names, but any random 64K values, numbers or Strings have a good chance of having the same hashCode. For the numbers you can easily calculate when you get a collision.

Comment: Also if you have Strings which are "Xxxx 2" and "Xxxx 3" and "Xxxx 4" (film names are known to do) they will have the hashCode, one apart. From this you can calculate how much difference you need from numero and fornitura to give the same hashCode.

Comment: I would not express it as "good chance". The chance is much less than the 1 dividd by the number of films that exist in world

Comment: I don't see how this guarantees uniqueness. Despite clear overflow issues that might arise when numero and fornitura are high enough, you can always fix one variable and vary the others and then repeat the process fixing another variable and letting the others vary in order to produce the same code.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner There is no garuantee. (I will update the text)  But who needs one? If the chance of an error is less than one in a billion who matters? The whole life and whole businness is all a question of probability. Life has no garuantee.Either go the expensive way using a unique id data (base) or create one that is likely unique.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Overflow is by design, as for all hashcode functions, and not an issue.

Comment: @AlexWien I meant overflow not for hash codes, but for generating a unique code. Anyway, I agree with you in that there's no need at all to generate unique IDs. Actually, that's why hash tables exist ;)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, yes overflow in unqiue ids is no problem, it gets negative, as long as it is unqiue, its ok.